# How read partition stats via V3 SDK

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In the V2 SDK, DocumentCollection exposed a PartitionKeyRangeStatistics object that contained statistics about the collection including the number of partitions and the number/size of documents in each partition.  I don't see the same info on the Container/ContainerResponse objects in the V3 SDK.  Is it possible to get the same partition stats via the V3 SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Comsos)?